# Create a NuGet package after a TFS buld and deploy

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild, nuget

What is the best way to make a .dll available as a NuGet package in a local environment so that others can download that and use it whenever they want. We use TFS as the CI server and I want NuGet package (with a version number) to be copied to a location in the intranet after every build so that users can pull it when they want. (Do not want to push). I want this to happen from the all the feature branches, any feature branch other than main needs to package this as a beta. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't exactly what you're looking for but I heard about this a few weeks ago. https://www.nuget.org/packages/CreateNewNuGetPackageFromProjectAfterEachBuild/

Comment: Tx a lot, that's is a perfect fit for my job. Put this as an answer so that I can select it as a correct solution to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CreateNewNuGetPackageFromProjectAfterEachBuild/

This will build a nuget package whenever you build.